# Can't access attributes table in for rasters in QGIS

Tags: raster, qgis

I can't access any attributes tables in any of my rasters (.tif files) in QGIS, and now the only attribute table option is "Load a new Raster Attribute Table from a VAT.DBF file".

I've checked my file privacy settings on my computer and attribute table settings in QGIS and they all seem fine. Anything else I should check/might be going wrong?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can not obtain attribute table option by adding raster file but you can create it according to symbology of raster layer. For that you should install the plugin "RasterAttributeTable" and then right click to your layer, new attribute table, it will create an attribute table with your symbology classification.